# Why does $my_item->save fail with Rose::DB::Object?

Tags: rose-db-object

I am trying to do a simple addition of data to a database table (PostgreSQL).  At first, I couldn't even get a simple

```
$my_item = $_item_class->new(...);
```

to work.  I discovered I had spelled a field differently in my code from what I had in my "model" code.

But, now, this is working, but when I try:

```
$my_item->save;
```

it seems an exception is thrown.  All this is occurring in an eval {...} structure and I would like to catch the exception and see what is going wrong, but I don't know how to do that.

Why would something like the "save" be failing here?  I have checked everything, and all seems right (of course!).

And, how do I catch the exception that seems to be being thrown?

Thank you!

Comment: It would help to see your database schema, the code for `$_item_class`, or at least some sort of error message.

Comment: Thank you John.  I have figured out this issue and I will make a post about it soon.  Yes, the database schema and the $_item_class code was the key.

Comment: You should answer your own question here so other people can see the solution.

Comment: Yes, I definitely will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured all this out myself.  It was simple.  I had duplicated a field in my class somehow when I had done an edit to it.  That was all.  The class just had two identically named fields specified in the hash table in the class, both with identical characteristics.  When I removed one of these, the code worked.

With regard to my second question about how to catch the exception, I had to learn how to have an

```
if ($@) {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

right after my "eval {...}" structure.  Because I am new to Perl, I didn't understand that.  But, it was actually pretty easy to figure out.  My problem was that I was working from some code as a model for me that didn't do that but named specific exceptions that were thrown in its "eval {...}" code.  So, I thought that I had to have the names of exceptions that could be thrown by Rose::DB::Object calls, but I couldn't find any such exceptions in the documentation.  When I learned about "if ($@) {...}", I was able to print out the reported exception in $@ and from that I was able to see the problem with the duplicate field I mentioned above.

That was all there was to it.  Everything is working just fine now.

Comment: Since you’re new to Perl, you might want to read the documentation for Try::Tiny to learn some of the pitfalls of `eval { ... }` and `$@`: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Try-Tiny/lib/Try/Tiny.pm#BACKGROUND